# c++: print string vector returned by function

Tags: c++, vector, cout

So essentially I have a private `std::vector<std::string> alloc` in `class A` which has some manipulation etc done on it by public method `std::vector<std::string> allocMethod()` and this method then does `return alloc`. The method is called in `class B`

In `class B` I want to print the return value of `allocMethod`, i.e the `alloc` vector. This is what I have

```
std::cout << A.allocMethod();
```

I know that normally one would use some sort of interator and loop to print out a vector but I don't think I can do that as it is a functions return value being printed not actually a vector.

Note: I reeaaally don't wan't to have to just print out the vector in `class A`.

Is there a way to output the `std::vector<string>` result as shown above?

Comment: Just overload `operator<<`.

Comment: What about looping through that result vector and print the values. Alternatively you could provide an operator overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const std::vector<std::string>>&)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Note: I reeaaally don't wan't to have to just print out the vector in class A."*

As you want to use this repeatedly it might be worth it to provide an appropriate output operator overload for `std::vector<std::string>`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const std::vector<std::string>>& vs) {
    for (const auto& s : vs) {
        os << s << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

That should allow for just calling

```
std::cout << A.allocMethod();
```

---

You can even try a more generic overload

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const std::vector<T>>& vs) {
    for (const auto& s : vs) {
        os << s << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you couldn't point me to a resource which would explain what is going on in the first bit of code could you please?

Comment: @user3001499 What exactly do you mean? The [operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)?

Comment: Yeah, not really sure what's going and I don't like to use code which I don't understand (causes massive chaos later)

Comment: @user3001499 Well, I suppose, you already know you can overload the operators for class/struct's?

Comment: yes, I think I get it now, so you have overloaded the output operator `<<` with the standard output stream functionality (as it normally has) as well as adding to it functionality to output a vector (`vs`) (as defined in the for loop). Is this about right?

Comment: @user3001499 _"Is this about right?"_ Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to your believe, you can print the vector by iterating over it although it is a temporary using the C++11 for-loop like this:

```
for (const auto& i : A.allocMethod())
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: To cite the OP: _"I know that normally one would use some sort of interator and loop to print out a vector"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *"but I don't think I can do that"*. Yes, he can, just like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the return value and then iterate over it. Like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> result = allocMethod();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << result[i];
}
```

Comment: To cite the OP: _"I know that normally one would use some sort of interator and loop to print out a vector"_

Comment: He said he thought he couldn't do that because it was a return value, so I showed how he could.